# lead conversion page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lead-conversion

I want to add new check list field to lead convesion page .
when the checkbox is true(checked) i want to create the lead details in one of the custom object in my org along with account , contact , oppertunities.
can you please tell me the easiest way to achive this?
is it possible to edit the standard lead conversion page?
plese help me

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in standard page. You need to write custom page and logic to implement this.

You can also do one thing. Create the checkbox on lead record and check that before lead conversion. And when the lead is converted you can use trigger to create the record.

if you want to convert lead in apex then you can refer this.

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);
lc.ConvertedStatus = 'Closed - Converted';
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);                
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```